# What does "likelihood" mean in the image?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, predictive-modeling, statistics

It is about insurance fraud. The image 1 shows the result of analysis with likelihood of claim referral, which is the target variable, from the previous analysis, image 2, on historical referral data. How should I interpret the likelihood in the image?

- Link to the document: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/1837-2014.pdf

[image]

Image 1.

[image]
Image 2

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine likelihood is the same as it is in statistics:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function